# Font weight only work with bold ones. Other doesnt work

Tags: css, fonts, cross-browser, font-face, font-family

I am loading fonts from my local for website. @font-face doesnt work properly. Some font weights doesnt work. Only work bold ones. When I changed font weight for light,lighter,400-500 etc it doesnt work.  I'm stuck completely. Anybody help?

My Network:
[image: network]
My Computed:
[image: computed]
My Files:
[image: files]

```
    @font-face {
  font-family: "Gotham Narrow";
  src: local("../font/gothamnarrow-thin-webfont.woff2") format("woff2");
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Gotham Narrow";
  src: local("../font/gothamnarrow-light-webfont.woff2") format("woff2");
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Gotham Narrow";
  src: local("../font/gothamnarrow-book-webfont.woff2") format("woff2");
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Gotham Narrow";
  src: local("../font/gothamnarrow-medium-webfont.woff2") format("woff2");
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Gotham Narrow";
  src: local("../font/gothamnarrow-bold-webfont.woff2") format("woff2");
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "Gotham Narrow";
  src: local("../font/gothamnarrow-ultra-webfont.woff2") format("woff2");
  font-weight: 800;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Gotham Narrow";
  src: local("../font/gothamnarrow-black-webfont.woff2") format("woff2");
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: When I'm using font like that, meaning loading different fonts, £I'm giving different name. All your fonts have Gotham Narrow font family name. You should have font-family "Gotham Narrow" for the gotham narrow book (for example), "Gotham Narrow Medium" ... If you use a font which have the different styles inside font definition-file, you could use with same name bold, italic... In your case seems each file has 1 style only, so needed different names, one for each

Comment: Actually I tried that way too but doesnt work. Should I add to one by one each style for font family? Because I added only body tag font family. like font-family:"Gotham Narrow  Bold","Gotham Narrow  Medium"..........

Comment: You've shown your @font-face rules. Those are declaring font resources that will be available for styling in the rest of the CSS. But you haven't shown any of the CSS where you try to use them. You should add that to your question. Also, it might not matter, but I'd remove the trailing space in the font-family descriptor, "Gotham Narrow " (change to "Gotham Narrow").

Comment: Please stick to `url()` – [`local()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) is **not a replacement** and another story (and your markup won't work this way) - let's focus on your font file urls. Provided, your style.css resides in the css directory - it should work as expected. If your font-face rules are inlined in your HTML header it won't. Please close the "whats new" tab and switch to the console tab. The network indicates no fonts are loaded

Answer (score 0):

what I was saying is the following:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Gotham Narrow";
  src: url("assets-new/font/GothamNarrow-Book.eot") ;
  src: url("assets-new/font/GothamNarrow-Book.eot?#iefix")
      format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("assets-new/font/GothamNarrow-Book.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("assets-new/font/GothamNarrow-Book.woff") format("woff"),
    url("assets-new/font/GothamNarrow-Book.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("assets-new/font/GothamNarrow-Book.svg#GothamNarrow-Book") format("svg");

  font-style: 400;
  font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Gotham Narrow Medium";
  src: url("assets-new/font/GothamNarrow-Medium.eot")
    ;
  src: url("assets-new/font/GothamNarrow-Medium.eot?#iefix")
      format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("assets-new/font/GothamNarrow-Medium.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("assets-new/font/GothamNarrow-Medium.woff") format("woff"),
    url("assets-new/font/GothamNarrow-Medium.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("assets-new/font/GothamNarrow-Medium.svg#GothamNarrow-Medium")
      format("svg");

  font-style: 500;
  font-display: swap;
}

div1 {
  font-family: "Gotham Narrow";
}
div2 {
  font-family: "Gotham Narrow Medium";
}
```

You could also use css variables (after font face declaration):

```css
:root {
    --font-primary: "Gotham Narrow", sans-serif;
    --font-primary-medium: "Gotham Narrow Medium", sans-serif;

}
div1 {
  font-family: var(--font-primary);
}
div2 {
  font-family: var(--font-primary-medium);
}
```

Comment: Hi again. Thanks for detiald I understood what you said. Im just saying How can Iadd all font familys just body tag? I cant add one by one each component because there 50 html page and dozen of components I have. I tried your solution but didnt work for body.

Comment: Hello you can't put 5 or 10 font-family in 1!!! Try to use variables, depending of context (which page is open) you just change the body font-family to the new variable

Comment: This is a strange approach which is not what is intended in the CSS Font Module spec. There's no need to use CSS variables, and no reason why multiple faces can't be included in a single font family -- that's what CSS assumes.

Comment: You both have used font-style incorrectly: that attribute pertains to italics or oblique, not weight or width. See https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-5/, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Web_fonts

Comment: @PeterConstable Ah thanks for attention. I wrote wrong, but my local was true. Edited my question. So my problem is still contiunes

Answer (score 0):

#### Search for typos in the `@font-face` rules

As pointed out by @Peter Constable:
typos in your `@font-face` rule will break it

```
font-family: "Gotham Narrow "; /* trailing space - won'work */
```

#### Inspect your page via your dev tools

Quite likely, your **fonts are not loaded** and the bold font you can see is actually a locally installed Gotham.

Check the **computed style tab:**

[image: dev tools: computed style]

Screenshot above: Font is replaced by a locally installed (OS) "Gotham" font – worth mentioning: the browser replaced the intended "Gotham Narrow" with a regular "Gotham" – not condensed. (thanks to @Peter Constable for pointing this out.)

If a font URL is wrong, you'll see a log like this in your console.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

You should also check the **network tab** for loaded fonts.

[image: dev tools network tab]

Try this example and replace the the `src` URLs with your paths.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Gotham Narrow";
  src: url("https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOkCnqEu92Fr1MmgVxIIzI.woff2") format("woff2");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Gotham Narrow";
  src: url("https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxK.woff2") format("woff2");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Gotham Narrow";
  src: url("https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmWUlfBBc4.woff2") format("woff2");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Gotham Narrow";
  src: url("https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmYUtfBBc4.woff2") format("woff2");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-display: swap;
}
/** wrong url/path */
@font-face {
  font-family: "Gotham Narrow";
  src: url("https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxK-wrong.woff2") format("woff2");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 1000;
  font-display: swap;
}

/* default for body */
body{
  font-family: "Gotham Narrow";
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size:2em;
}

h1{
    font-weight: 900
}
h1,h2{
  font-size:1.5em
}

h2,
strong{
    font-weight: 700
}


.light{
  font-weight: 100;
}

.regular{
  font-weight: 400;
}

.bold{
  font-weight: 900;
}

.heavy{
  font-weight: 900;
}

/** doesn't exist **/
.ultra{
  font-weight: 1000;
}
```

```html
<h1>Font weight 900</h1>
<h2>Font weight 700</h2>
<p>Font weight 400 <strong>Font weight 700</strong> <span class="light">Font weight 100</span> <span class="ultra">Font weight 1000 - doesn't exist</span></p>
```

#### Make sure your weights and styles are applied

Most browsers will "lazyload" fonts:
If a font isn't used anywhere – it won't be loaded.

I recommend to set the `font-weight:400` as a default for your body.
Since you have multiple levels of bold you need to specify, if a `<strong>` element should use `font-weight:700` or `font-weight:900` (same for headings like h1-h5)

```
body{
  font-family: "Gotham Narrow";
  font-weight: 400;
}

h2,
strong{
    font-weight: 700
}
```

#### Common mistake: relative paths

Paths might change while compiling your css – e.g. you're combining css snippets via scss/sass.

#### Corrupted font files – rather rare

Once again – check your dev tools console for logs like these:

> Failed to decode downloaded font:

> OTS parsing error

These issues usually occur, after file conversions (in less capable applications) like these:

- font format conversions (e.g. ttf to woff2)
- character subsetting
- upload filters (trying to sanitize the uploaded file)

... and sometimes a font file might as well become invalid  due to file system corruption.

Comment: Actually, while the font is being declared as "Gotham Narrow", the browser could be locating the "Gotham Narrow" font, treating the font's Narrow as a font-stretch attribute, and the family as "Gotham". I probably would have started by trying to declare the font-family as "Gotham".

Comment: That's a good point (as always!):  there's more "auto font name mapping" happening in the browser. The computed style screenshot shows a local version of a regular "Gotham" (not a condensed/narrow one).  I've never experienced any auto `font-stretch` overriding due to font-family names **as long as the font file URL (define by `@font-face` src property) is correct** – but there might be exceptions (... or safari ;). I'd be thankful, if you could share an example of such an exception. However, I still believe the OP's issue is related to incorrect file URLs/paths or errors in css rules.

Comment: @herrstrietzel Thanks for detiled answer. I edited my queiston with ss could you look please?

Comment: @PeterConstable I tried that but didnt work