# Custom web font special character not working in WebKit (iOS/Safari) but works on Chrome

Tags: ios, font-face

I am using a custom web font from a type foundry, called herbier,  that is made up of characters.

How can i view this font on all browsers?
Chrome works fine, but Safari and iOS turn the type into numerals.
[this is an example of the font working on safari from the original website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI1U0.png)
I am using amazon aws to host this site.

I have looked up many explanations.
changing the display: swap, text to italic, redownloading the text files, urls i use link to the fonts uploaded to my domain, i tried using text-rendering: optimizeLegibility and downloaded the web kit so i would have all svg, woff, woff versions of this font etc etc.

The specimen file has said ' The most common problem here is that you are serving the fonts from an IIS server. IIS refuses to serve files that have unknown MIME types. If that is the case, you must set the MIME type for SVG to "image/svg+xml" in the server settings.'

Is there any simple way to solve this?

Example code for a different font that works :

```
@font-face { 
        font-family: Director-light;
        src: url('https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/object/www.MYWEBSITE.net?region=eu-west-1&prefix=Director-Light.otf'); src: url('https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/object/www.MYWEBSITE.net?region=eu-west-1&prefix=FT88-School.ttf'); } 
 @font-face { font-family: Director-light; font-weight: bold; src: url('Director-Light.otf');}
    h3 {
        font-size: 15px;
        color: navy;
font-family: Director-light; 
    }
```

The font i am using at the moment :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'hershey-noaillnoaillesherbier';
    src: url('hershey-noailles-herbier-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('hershey-noailles-herbier-webfont.woff') format('woff');
etcc etc 

}
```

Comment: sorry there is an error in my first @font-face, but this was just an example of how i am writing the code for this font

Comment: Please clarify, how the safari rendering differs from chrome's. Most of these issues occur, when your font isn't loaded due to wrong urls/paths - you might see a locally installed version on your desktop chrome.  Try this [troubleshooting list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74655872/font-weight-only-work-with-bold-ones-other-doesnt-work/74668383#74668383). Make sure all aws hosted assets are publically available - maybe your settings are currently restricted to logged in users etc.